# Form submits as GET Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have form like this

```
<form action="{{ Request::root() }}/articles/update/" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $article->id }}" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And route like this

```
Route::post('articles/update', array('as' => 'articleUpdate', 'uses' => 'ArticlesController@update'));
```

But when I submit the form, I get `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. In error report I can see that request method is GET. I have also tried using caps for method `method="POST"` but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: the problem is more likely in laravel's configuration, if it `$_GET` your fields, it won't work if you `POST` them

Comment: I have another POST route that works. It was for login. But this one won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does FireBug/Web console inspector show you? is the form being sent via GET or POST, any redirects?

Seems a redirection problem to me, after reaching the server Laravel redirects to the URL the form sent the post request.

Comment: It seems that I have "Moved permanently - 301" for POST request, and than same request with GET method that fails.

Comment: Another thing I have noticed that it redirects without trailing slash although form action has trailing slash. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the trailing slash from the form and test again. If this is the problem then the `.htaccess` needs to ignore these redirections when POST information is received

Comment: Works when I remove trailing slash. How should I edit `.htaccess` ?

Comment: I needed to add to my `.env` file this `REDIRECT_HTTPS=false` and it fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

you must use put method here. Form  change like this

```
 {{Form::open(array('url'=>'/articles/update','method' => 'PUT'))}}
```

Routes like this

```
 Route::put('/articles/update','ArticlesController@update');
```