# laravel form post issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am building a practice app with the `Laravel` framework I built a form in one of the views which is set to *post* to the same view itself but when I hit submit the form is posted however I do not get the desired output, I see the original view again.

Here is my view *index.blade.php*

```
@extends('master')

@section('container')

<div class="wrapper">

    {{ Form::open(array('url' => '/', 'method' => 'post')) }}
        {{ Form::text('url') }}
        {{ Form::text('valid') }}
        {{ Form::submit('shorten') }}
    {{ Form::close() }}

</div><!-- /wrapper -->

@stop
```

and my *routes.php*

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
return View::make('index'); 
});

Route::post('/', function() 
{
return 'successfull';
});
```

What I've tried so far

- I tried changing the post to a different view and it worked.
  However I want the form to post to the same view itself.
- Instead of returning a string I tried to return make a view still it
  didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

### addendum

I see that when the form is making the post request I am getting a `301 MOVED PERMANENTLY HEADER`

Comment: Route::any('/', function()
{
return View::make('index'); 
});

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do??

Comment: Can you show me the result when you use the `index` view file in your `POST` route?

Comment: 1) What URL are you using to access the form? 2) What *other* routes do you have defined?

Comment: @TryingTobemyselfRahul what I want to do is that when someone submits the form it gets posted to the same view itself and I see the 'success' message. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Trung-HieuLe I see the exact same view and nothing changes its just like the page refreshes. I am supposed to see the successfull message right. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @fideloper I am using the home url in my case it is shorten.dev/ which points to localhost:8888/shorten/public/ basically it is the home route and I have no other Routes Defined. this is the whole content of the routes.php file. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Is this the exact code are you trying with? Because its working for me, can you show your code?

Comment: @Ragzor - great, so you are able to view the site at `shorten.dev/`? I think you see my point - your form being set to submit to `/`, which should be going to `shorten.dev/` and not to `localhost:8888/` since your code is not "listening" at `localhost:8888/`.

Comment: hello @TryingTobemyselfRahul yes it is exactly the same code

Comment: @fideloper yes I tried that as well :/ i removed the alias shortened.dev/ and went back to the regular localhost localhost:8888 and I also tried removing and adding the slash '/' but chrome seems to automatically inserting the slash.

Comment: did you try in another browser?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => ' ', 'method' => 'post')) }}
```

Passing a space as the url has worked for me.

Comment: Route::post('/', 'UserController@login');
doesn't work unless the form url is empty, this is true only for post to homepage

Comment: worked for me too, but does anyone know why this weird issue?

Answer (score 2):

I think this post: [Form submits as GET Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240767/form-submits-as-get-laravel-4) is related to your problem. I think the problem as I undersood it is caused by end a form url with a / . I found this when having problems to using post to a ./ url in my form. There is also a bug at github that seems like it is related https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1804.

I know this is an old question but I found this thread having the same problem so hopefully someone else is helped by my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your form's method **does NOT end in a /** for it to be routed correctly. For example if you have the following route:

```
Route::post('form/process', function()
{
   # code here ...    
});
```

Then you need to have the following form definition:

```
<form action="/form/process" method="POST">
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem with OSx + MAMP, initially I've resolved with Raul's solution:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => ' ', 'method' => 'post')) }}
```

but after consultation with my friend we have concluded that my problem was due to the fact
my lavarel project is avaliable by long local path, as:

```
 http://localhost/custom/custom2/...
```

**in this location the post/get method on root path ("/") not working correctly.**

Lavarel to working correctly must be avaliable by "vhost", in this case the problem get/post method on root location "/" not exist.

My friend advised me to use http://www.vagrantup.com/

BYE

Answer (score 0):

There is some helpfull information in the Laravel Docs. Check these out:

- [Resource Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) (or [RESTful Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers))
- [Forms & HTML](http://laravel.com/docs/html)

  - [Opening A Form](http://laravel.com/docs/html#opening-a-form)
- [Routing](http://laravel.com/docs/routing)

  - [Named Routes](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes)

I recommend you read the [Resource Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) documentation as it makes form handling a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just return the view, so nothing change. You should bind your route to a controller to do some logic and add data to your view, like this:

**`index.blade.php`**

```
@extends('master')

@section('container')

<div class="wrapper">
     @if (isset($message))
     <p>{{$message}}</p>
     @endif

    {{ Form::open(array('url' => '/', 'method' => 'post')) }}
        {{ Form::text('url') }}
        {{ Form::text('valid') }}
        {{ Form::submit('shorten') }}
    {{ Form::close() }}

</div><!-- /wrapper -->

@stop
```

Your routes

```
Routes::any('/', 'home@index');
```

You controller `HomeController.php`

```
public function index()
{
     $data = array();
     $url = Input::get('url');
     if ($url)
          $data['message'] = "foo";

     return View::make('index', $data);
}
```

You can also modify your current routes without using a controller like this (use the new view file)

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
     return View::make('index'); 
});

Route::post('/', function() 
{
     return View::make('index')->with('message', 'Foo');          
});
```

Comment: Hello!Thanks alot for the reply, Yes this is the correct way of doing it However this is also not working in this case I found out that when the app is making a post request I get a 301 moved permanently header so it just gets back to the get request and I see the default view. I tried the same thing on laravel 3 and it was working. No clue what is going on here :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with defualt slashed in Apache from 2.0.51 and heigher:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash

The best solution if you do not want to change Apache config is to make the post in a different path:

GOOD:

```
Route::get('/', 
  ['as' => 'wizard', 'uses' => 'WizardController@create']);

Route::post('wizard-post', 
  ['as' => 'wizard_store', 'uses' => 'WizardController@store']);
```

NOT GOOD:

```
Route::get('/', 
  ['as' => 'wizard', 'uses' => 'WizardController@create']);

Route::post('/', 
  ['as' => 'wizard_store', 'uses' => 'WizardController@store']);
```