# Laravel cannot get a POST in index (/)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am having a search form in the index view of my application, however whenever I submit it, it will redirect back to the homepage. Looking at Chrome's Network Tab, I saw a `302 Move Permanently` status code when submitted. What I am trying to do is, I am getting the user keywords, storing them and redirecting to a search page.

**Edit:**
After searching abit, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511653/laravel-form-post-issue) similar question as well. The answer provided did not solved my problem.

In routes.php

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'PagesController@home']);

/.../

Route::group(['before' => 'csrf'], function()
{
    Route::post('/', ['as' => 'post-search', 'uses' => 'UserController@postSearch']);
});
```

My form:

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('post-search') }}" method="POST" class="form-inline search">
    {{ Form::token() }}
    <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ trans('form.search') }}">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">
</form>
```

Finally, my controller method:

```
public function postSearch()
{
    $fields = Input::all();

    $rules = [ 'search' => 'required' ];

    $validator = Validator::make($fields, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return 'Validation did not work.';
    }
    else
    {
        $search = Input::get('search');

        return Redirect::route('search', $search);
    }

    return 'Something terrible happened.';
}
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yea, my fault there. But it seems like that the postSearch() method is not even triggered.

Comment: Strange, your exact code (minus the PageController and redirect to "search" route) works perfectly on my side.

Comment: That is very strange indeed, I tried with Firefox, but I got a 302 Move Permanently status code as well!

Comment: What's your Laravel version ? Did you install any third-party packages ? Did you do `composer dump-autoload` ? (even though my attempt worked without doing that)

Comment: Nope, I have a clean Laravel 4.2 installation , with no third-party packages. I also executed that command, but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you try using a clean installation just like I did ? Maybe it's a web-server configuration issue and has nothing to do with Laravel.

Comment: How is your 'search' route set up?

Comment: Remove the token from the form and also the token check from d route lets see if it works

Comment: It happens to cause errors sometimes when the token from your form is different from the session's token

Comment: Seems promising guys, I will do that in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I have had something like this before, it happened when the csrf token stored in the session is different from the one generated from the form.
So, Modify your code  lets see what happens.

> From

```
Route::group(['before' => 'csrf'], function()
```

{
    Route::post('/', ['as' => 'post-search', 'uses' => 'UserController@postSearch']);
});

> TO`

```
Route::post('/', ['as' => 'post-search', 'uses' => 'UserController@postSearch']);
```

if it works this way then you'll have to clear your browsers cookies and sessions befor you re-enable csrf