# Post Method Not Working in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, post, laravel, laravel-blade

Form:

```
@section('form')
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        {!! Form::open() !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('name', 'Enter your name', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('contact', 'Contact Number:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('contact', 'Enter your contact number', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('location', 'Location:') !!}
            {!! Form::select('location', $locations, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('service', 'Service Required:') !!}
            {!! Form::select('service', $services, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::submit('Just go Befikr >>', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
@stop
```

routes.php:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::post('/', 'PagesController@store');
```

PagesController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\service_location;
use App\service_type;
use App\service_request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Request;

class PagesController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {        
        $locations = service_location::lists('location_area', 'location_id');
        $services = service_type::lists('service_desc', 'service_id');

        return view('home.index', compact('locations','services'));
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $input = Request::all();            
        return $input;
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, the code neither seems to return `$input` on the screen (implying that its not executing the `store()` function at all), nor does it throw any error/exception.

Can anyone please let me know why the `post` method is not resulting in appropriate results here?

---

**Edit 1**

I attempted to directly `return` via the `route`'s inline function, but even that didn't work. Hence, now I'm pretty confident that the `post` method is not getting triggered at all. This is what I did to verify it:

```
Route::post('/', function()
{
    return 'Hello';
});
```

Comment: You're likely hitting http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection. I'm dubious about the "no exception" bit - check your logs.

Comment: @ceejayoz How am I supposed to check my logs? I'm new to this. Pardon me if this sounds silly.

Comment: `storage/logs` has text files with log information in them.

Comment: @ceejayoz Nothing in the logs either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured the answer to my own question here.

Turns out, that in order to be able to execute a `post` request, you need to explicitly deploy a PHP server as:

```
php -s localhost:<AnyFreePort> -t <YourRootDirectory>
```

Whereas when I attempted to run it the first time through XAMPP, I was attempting to run the application out of sheer laziness, directly as:

```
http://localhost/myproject/public
```

which worked fine for a `get` request.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had same issue, but your solution wasn't helpful for me since I was using Apache server instead of built in PHP server
then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511653/laravel-form-post-issue) solution which says just enter space to form action, weird issue and solution but it worked for me...

Eg.

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => ' ', 'method' => 'post')) !!}
```